# A nice tool to look up make/model via MAC address?

Tags: router, log-files, mac-address

The first several digits of a MAC address (Ethernet ID) are specific to its manufacturer/model. I won't ask what's *the best way* to look these up since it's subjective... but I'd love to know if any here has found a particularly efficient resource to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When online I use [MAC_Find:](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) - it's helpful if you're only looking up one or two.

If you're wanting to look up a larger amount or a list of MAC addresses it will be easier to run a script to grab the line (using `grep` or something similar) from [IEEE's OUI List](http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/oui.txt). Note that the oui.txt file seperates the MAC address by dashes rather than colons.

To make life a bit more fun here's a shell script to get the manufacturer's from whatever `arp` will give you:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get Mac Addresses, add missing 0s, only grab the first 8 characters, change to dashes and uppercase
arp -a | awk {'print toupper($4)'} | sed 's/^[0-9A-F]:/0&/g' | sed 's/:\([0-9A-F]\):/:0\1:/g' | cut -c 1-8 | sed 's/:/-/g' > /tmp/arp.txt

for line in `cat /tmp/arp.txt`
    do
    echo `grep $line /PATH/TO/oui.txt`
done

rm /tmp/arp.txt
```

Example Output:

```
00-00-5A (hex) SysKonnect GmbH
00-00-5A (hex) SysKonnect GmbH
00-03-93 (hex) Apple Computer, Inc.
00-17-F2 (hex) Apple Computer
00-17-F2 (hex) Apple Computer
00-0A-95 (hex) Apple Computer, Inc.
00-11-24 (hex) Apple Computer
00-16-CB (hex) Apple Computer
00-11-24 (hex) Apple Computer
00-17-F2 (hex) Apple Computer
00-16-CB (hex) Apple Computer
```

Comment: I've been using Coffer's tool over IEEE's for years.  Since it supports 3 different MAC display formats I find it more useful.  The only format I use that it doesn't support is Cisco, i.e. 0011.2233.4455.  The IEEE web form, however, only supports hyphens, whereas most command line tools use colons.

Comment: Going between the different formats is a PITA - hence the shell script I just added as part of my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I have written a small python script using regular expressions. Time to share it with the world: http://omploader.org/vMXFrNg/macreformat.py

Comment: @hayalci - Nice!

Answer (score 4):

The first 6 bytes of a MAC address represent the [OUI (Organizationally Unique Identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_Unique_Identifier). These are administered by the IEEE, so I find it best to always go to the source:

http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/index.shtml